# Getting the same instance of an EJB in both Filter and ManagedBean

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, servlet-filters, managed-bean, stateful-session-bean

I'm trying to add a Filter to my Java EE application but I'm facing some problems.

I want to use the filter for login purposes, so I need to let it "talk" with the *UserManager* bean that manages the login.

Here's my structure :

- LoginFilter : the ServletFilter
- LoginBean : a *SessionScoped Managed Bean*
- UserManager : the *Stateful Session Bean*

*UserManager* has to be accessed by both *LoginFilter* and *LoginBean* because it has the methods to deal with the login process.

While in *LoginBean* I get the *UserManager* with this simple line:

```
@EJB private UserManagerLocal userManager;
```

I can't do that in the *LoginFilter* so I had to write a lookup method:

```
try{
    Context c = new InitialContext();
    return (UserManagerLocal) c.lookup("java:global/PROJECT/PROJECT-ejb/UserManager!ejb.UserManagerLocal");
} catch (NamingException ex) {
    ...
}
```

I also had a line to add this *UserManagerLocal* to the request atrributes, but it throws a NPE because there's no request when I call the lookup method, so I moved it into the *doFilter()* method.

```
public void doFilter(...){
   HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
   if(req.getAttribute("userManager") == null){
      req.setAttribute("userManager", userManager);
   }
   ...
}
```

Now comes the problem.

*LoginFilter* and *LoginBean* uses **two different instances** of *UserManager*!
This makes my filter stop even the logged in users, because the *LoginBean* works on another instance of *UserManager* and so *LoginFilter* is not aware that the login has been done!

How can I fix it?
I thought that lookup and injection would return the same instance of a *SSFB*!

Comment: Have you tried with a [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnr.html) bean?

Comment: I can't use CDI beans in this project :(

Answer (score 1):

No it will return new instance. Even if you do the lookup in filter multiple times it will return different instances.

You need to maintain/use UserManagerLocal instance that you created in filter, instead of injecting UserManagerLocal in LoginBean get the same instance from request.